# load event of image in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am creating an image tag dynamically and on load event of image i want image's height and width.

```
I have following code


 var foreImage = $('<img/>')
.load(function () {
    alert( this.height + '  ' +  this.width );
}).attr("src", imageUrl);
```

Above code works in firefox and chrome but in IE 8 it fails.
any idea why?

Comment: How does it exactly *fails* on IE8? Load event is not tiggered? Size is wrong? the `src` is not correctly set?

Comment: shows height and width 0

Comment: Then look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10697684/width-and-height-of-image-are-zero-because-of-asynchronous-image-loading/10697722#10697722 - maybe it can help :)

Comment: See : http://api.jquery.com/load-event and the section where it says "Caveats of the load event when used with images". Easiest (yet ugliest) way to fix IE8- this would be appending a random query string to your src.

Comment: woking: http://jsfiddle.net/jwF9u/